# Changing the background of a WPF toolbar panel

Tags: c#, wpf, toolbar

I'm trying to reproduce a Visual Studio style toolbar with the two gradient backgrounds in C# code.  I can see how to do it in XAML, but how do I drill into the object to change the backgound of its 'MainPanelBorder' border in my C# code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the

```
myToolbar.Template.FindName("MainPanelBorder", myToolbar) as Panel 
   //Or whatever the type of the item is in the template.
```